# Where is the "Bake from multires" option for normal map baking in Cycles (Blender 2.78)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have sculpted detail into my mesh using a Multires modifier and now I want to bake that detail to a normal map, but I cannot find the option to bake from multires.

Comment: This is only available in Blender Internal.